# gorm golang self-referencing onetomany relationship in postgres

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to create a self-referencing ONE TO MANY reltionship using golang gorm. Each user can create multiple other users (Created), but a user is always created by one other user (UserID).

```
type User struct {
    ID        uint
    Mail      string
    Password  string
    AuthLevel uint
    Created   []User `gorm:"foreignkey:UserID"`
    UserID    uint
}

var db *gorm.DB
var err error
var (
    users = []User{
        {Mail: "JimmyJohnson@Test.com", Password: "1234", AuthLevel: 1, UserID: 0},
        {Mail: "HowardHills@Test.com", Password: "1234", AuthLevel: 2, UserID: 1},
        {Mail: "CraigColbin@Test.com", Password: "1234", AuthLevel: 2, UserID: 1},
    }
)

func main() {

    //Connection to db

    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
    for index := range users {
        db.Create(&users[index])
    }

    router.HandleFunc("/users/{id}", GetUser).Methods("GET")

    handler := cors.Default().Handler(router)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler))
}

//GetUser Returns one user by ID
func GetUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    var user User
    var users []User
    db.First(&user, params["id"])
    db.Debug().Model(&user).Related(&users)
    user.Created = users

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&user)
}
```

With this code the GetUser function returns the following for id = 1 :

```
{
  "ID": 1,
  "Mail": "JimmyJohnson@Test.com",
  "Password": "1234",
  "AuthLevel": 1,
  "Created": [
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "Mail": "HowardHills@Test.com",
      "Password": "1234",
      "AuthLevel": 2,
      "Created": null,
      "UserID": 1
    }
  ],
  "UserID": 2
}
```

So it looks like my relationship is set up the wrong way.

UserID is suppose to be referencing the ID of the creator, and when `db.Debug().Model(&user).Related(&users)` is called I would like it to query :
`SELECT * FROM "users"  WHERE ("user_id" = "id")` instead of `SELECT * FROM "users"  WHERE ("id" = "user_id")`.

So far the documentation or other similar questions havent been able to help me, as they are adressing many to many realtionships.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your user creation is a wrong way accutally, It is not clear what you want. Try to give clear it using an example .

Comment: You have to create parents user  then child user.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `db.Related` which is from the old version of the library. V2 has more robust methods for handling relations. If you're stuck in V1 the following may still work (I found `Related` in v1 to be buggy, but `Preload` should work).

In V2 this works as you expect:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID        uint
    Mail      string
    Password  string
    AuthLevel uint
    Created   []User `gorm:"foreignkey:UserID"`
    UserID    *uint
}

//...

user1 := User{Mail: "JimmyJohnson@Test.com", Password: "1234", AuthLevel: 1}
db.Create(&user1)

user2 := User{Mail: "HowardHills@Test.com", Password: "1234", AuthLevel: 2, UserID: &user1.ID}
db.Create(&user2)

var result User
db.Preload("Created").First(&result, user1.ID)
// result.Created[0] is user2
```

Note that I made the UserID an `*uint` and didn't give it a value when creating `user1`, this avoids a foreign key violation when trying to insert 0 for this column.

Also, by using `Preload` you don't have to make another call to `Related` or `Association`.

Answer (score 0):

Error on user2 initialization

`cannot use &node1.ID (type *uint) as type uint in field value`